# Airplane passenger point of view scene

Tags: game-design

I'm building a game with unity where a lot of scenes take place in an airplane as a passenger seated near the window, the airplane has to do a take off and a landing.

I can't find any examples of similar scenes anywhere on Internet. 
So I was wondering which would be the best approach to do this :

- Simulate the airplane physics, "checkpoints" system where the airplane travels through each checkpoints (**current solution**)
- Animate the airplane with the unity animator system (tried it but it feels really cheap)
- Static plane but make things move around him (possibility to have better lightings inside the plane as it is static)
- 360° Videos

The current solution works ok but I'm looking for improvements. I found the intro scene from *The Forest* pretty similar to what I'm trying to acheive here and I was wondering how they did it.

The current system works like this :

The plane has two engines script who control the speed of the plane. Another script controls the yoke, roll and pitch of the plane. And the last script is the 'Autopilot', each checkpoint tells the plane where to go and at whitch speed. You have to tweak the values until you have a good result which can be really time consuming.

Thank you !

Comment: *"The current solution works ok but I'm looking for improvements."*: What kind of improvements are you thinking about? What drawbacks did you recognize in your current solution and what are your priorities?

Comment: @Philipp My current solution isn't really easy to use, it works but if there is a better option it might be interesting to test it to see if I gain in performances. 
Now everything is done with the rigidbody of the plane and with colliders, etc...

Comment: What do you mean with "not easy to use"? What would you like to do with it and what problems do you encounter when you try?

Comment: @Philipp : Edited my orignal question with the current system mechanics.
I want to have three scenes : take off, in flight and landing of the plane.

Comment: Don't forget that the cabin and the PoV from which you view the outdoor scene don't need to literally be in the same place. You can use one camera to render the outside and an entirely different camera to render the inside, similar to rendering the view through a magic/sci-fi portal. That can let you have your cake and eat it too: each part of the scene can be static or moving independently.

Comment: @DMGregory maaaan, totaly forgot about that, that means that I can have my airplane static in another place and my environment static as well, all I have to animate is the camera rendering the view from the window right ? 
That could be the best way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already mentioned the best solution, make the plane static and change the surrounding area. Especially when you mention the Forest, it is clear that the view out of the window isn't as important as what is going on in the plane. When choosing you should always consider where the focus is on. In plane view or the outside. Both is easy changeable.

Comment: Actually in my case the window view is somewhat important because I want to focus the action of the scene on the Take Off of the plane. If you don't see through the window you don't really know that the plane is taking off :-)

Comment: @AntoineThiry You don't need to see outside to know that the plane is taking off or landing. You can _feel_ it. If that's what you're after, maybe you could consider alternatives to only the scene.

Comment: If it is always the same route the plane flies I would make a render of the scene and convert it

Comment: Yes it is always the same route, you mean render it as a video and project it outside the plane ?

Comment: Yes and animate the plane according to the video

Comment: @YoshSynergi I suggest you edit that in your answer :)